# What is the difference between expect_is and expect_type of the testthat package?

Tags: r, testthat

The R package `testthat` contains two I would say similar functions to test whether an object is of a certain type (integer, character, etc.): `expect_is()` and `expect_type()`. What is the difference between these two functions? The documentation states that `expect_is()` is an older form, but what about `expect_type()`? Maybe you could provide some examples of when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expect_is` tests the class, and `expect_type` tests the type. The documentation explains that `expect_type` compares with the output of R's base function `typeof`, and `expect_is` compares with the output from `class`.

So if I make a matrix of integers it has type "integer" and class "matrix":

```
> typeof(matrix(1:10,2,5))
[1] "integer"
> class(matrix(1:10,2,5))
[1] "matrix"
>
```

See the help for `typeof` and `class` for more information, and most introductions to R should discuss types and classes.

See also `mode` and `storage.mode`.